# Bathtub separating from wall

Tags: bathroom, tile, bathtub, caulking, crack

I recently bought an older house. It has had some work done in the master bath, and I just noticed that the tub is separating from the wall. What would be the best way to fix this? Oh I should mention we had the foundation leveled last week, so there are drywall cracks all over the house.[image: bathroom one]

Comment: is the separation due to work in the bathroom or the foundation?

Comment: i think there was some small separation before the foundation work, but then after the foundation was leveled it seemed to separate more

Answer (score 2):

Appearance of this crack has nothing to do with foundation; it is something that you can see in many bathrooms. First check if both wall and bathtub are vertical, if they are not this crack will most likely appear from time to time (every year or so).Now, you can do one of two things: You can use silicone to glue it together. Keep in mind that silicone (or similar material) should be replaced every 6-12 months you will know when to change because black dots will start to appear. Another thing you can do is that you can put a rubber band and just glue it to both sides. Now this solution is more permanent (you don't need to change it so often) but if you ask me it's not that pretty. Now, foundation....since you did all that work maybe (if possible) you should give your house couple of months or a year to settle before you start doing anything.

Comment: Ok, I will look into the Silicone for right now, just to prevent any more water from going into those cracks until the house settles. On the backside of this wall there is a crack from the foundation repair and the bottom of the crack has turned a slight brown, leading me to believe that water has gotten into the wall through the gap in the bathtub/tile. At least that is what I hope the brown stain is from

Comment: Even if the ceramic tiles have cracked this shouldn't cause any problem with water, because ceramic tiles aren't waterproofing layer. Some mold may appear since crack is small and it cannot be ventilated. Waterproofing layer under ceramic should stop the water from penetrating inside the wall if it is done properly, but now that I think since you had foundation issue it is possible that waterproofing layer has suffered damage especially if it is not elastic. If you want to be on a safe side you should remove ceramic tiles in that part and take a look at waterproofing.

Comment: But since it's not simple and cheap maybe you can make sure that water doesn't get there at all, but that's also not easy.